# Remove beginning of string where characters do not match

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Say I have this url:

```
git+https://github.com/ORESoftware/npp.git
```

I want to remove the first characters that do not match "http". I also want to remove the .git, but not sure how to do that reliably.

So I am looking to get this string:

```
https://github.com/ORESoftware/npp
```

as a total side conversation, not sure how that url differs from:

```
www.github.com/ORESoftware/npp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
let s = 'git+https://github.com/ORESoftware/npp.git';
console.log(s.replace(/^.*?(http.*?)\.git$/, '$1'))
```

Output:

```
https://github.com/ORESoftware/npp
```

This regex works as follows:

`^.*?` is a non-greedy match from the beginning of the string until the next element which does match, in this case the `(http.*?)` capturing group.

`(http.*?)` is a capturing group which captures everything from the `http` until the next match (since `.*?` is again non-greedy)

`\.git$` matches a trailing `.git` on the string.

The replacement string `$1` replaces the contents of the original string with only the contents of the capturing group. In this case that is everything from `http` until the last character before `.git`.

Comment: thanks, I understand how you remove the git+, but I don't understand how you are removing the .git...perhaps you could make it two separate ops for clarity? I also don't understand what the '$1' is for

Comment: also, I can't decide if the ^ char is necessary at the beginning or not, I don't think so

Comment: oh I see, so $1 is the first or second match, which you will keep

Comment: I've added an explanation of how it works. You may be right about the `^` but it's safer with it in case you get a URL that contains the string `http` inside it.

Comment: Is non-greedy the same as non-capturing?

Comment: Normally `.*` would match every character in a string (being "greedy"). By adding the `?`, you make it non-greedy, so that it stops matching when it hits something that matches the next expression in the regex.